# CakePHP testing user model with parentNode() method

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to learn how to do unit testing in general but specifically the project I'm working on is built with CakePHP. I have this parentNode() method in my user model taken directly from the [Simple Acl Controlled Application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html) tutorial.

```
public function parentNode() {
    if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
        $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
    } else {
        $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
    }
    if (!$groupId) {
        return null; // not tested
    } else {
        return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
    }
}
```

I wrote the following tests

```
public function testParentNodeHasNoUserDataOrId() {
    unset($this->User->id);
    unset($this->User->data);
    $this->assertNull($this->User->parentNode());
}

public function testParentNodeWithGroupIDInUserData() {
    $this->User->data['User']['group_id'] = 1;
    $this->assertEquals(array('Group'=>array('id'=>1)),$this->User->parentNode());
}

public function testParentNodeWithoutGroupIDInUserData() {
    $this->User->id = 1;
    unset($this->User->data['User']['group_id']);
    $this->assertEquals(array('Group'=>array('id'=>1)), $this->User->parentNode());
}
```

and they all seem to work. My code coverage report however shows that I'm not testing the `return null;` in the `if(!$groupId)` block. I can't figure out how to test that line.

As far as I can tell it will never execute. If my User model has no id and no data it returns null in the first if block. if I cheat a bit and give the user some fake data `$this->field('group_id')` is still returning group 1 (I think it [should return false instead](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field) but it doesn't)

So when unit testing do you have to test everything? How could I test for the `return null if(!$groupId)`? If there's code that will never execute should I just remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how I could test for the "impossible" scenario with the following test

```
public function testParentNodeWhenUserHasNoGroupId() {
    $this->User->id = 1;
    $user = $this->User->read();
    $user['User']['group_id'] = 0;
    $this->User->save($user);
    $this->assertNull($this->User->parentNode());
}
```